# Prove that the function f(x) = cosh(x)+ cos(x) is strictly increasing for non-negative x

Tags: real-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

I know that using the **mean value theorem** I should get $f'(x) =$ sinh$(x)$ - sin$(x)$, but from that on I have no ideas on how to show that $f'(x) > 0$ in the specified interval.
Basic trigonometric identities may be used.
Also any methods other than the mean value theorem will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function, $f'(x)$, is zero at $x=0$.  Can you show that its derivative - that is, $f''(x)$, is positive on $x>0$?

Comment: Oops I wasn't aware of the second derivative here. Thank you for the answer.